# pyinstaller struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 16

Tags: python, windows, icons, pyinstaller

trying to add an icon to my exe using pyinstaller but I get the above error!

See this for more info: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2445

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turn out that my icon file is not accepted by pyinstaller. Do not download your icon from google images as `png` then change the extention to `ico`, for some reason that does not work at all